# Javascript release resources automatically (like RAII)

Tags: javascript, raii

My general question is what techniques can I use to ensure that resources are cleaned up/released in Javascript? Currently, I am taking the C (without goto) approach of finding every execution path to a return or exception in my functions and ensuring clean up occurs.

My specific example is this: In Node.js I am using mutexes (through file locks) in object member functions (I need the mutual exclusion, because I run multiple instances of the Node.js application and have race conditions when different instances interact with the file system).

For example, in C++ I would do something like the following:

```
void MyClass::dangerous(void) {
     MyLock lock(&this->mutex);
     ...
     // at the end of this function, lock will be destructed and release this->mutex.
}
```

As far as I can tell, JavaScript doesn't provide any RAII functionality. In C, I would use `goto`s to unwind my resource allocation in the event of an error so that I only have one return path from a function.

What are some techniques to achieve a similar effect in Javascript?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As others might have noted, you'll want to use try/finally. Creating a wrapper function to simulate the lifetime scope will likely be more comfortable coming from c++. Try running the following code in the javascript console to get an example of its usage:

##### C++ Style

```
class MockFileIO {
    constructor(path) {
        console.log("Opening file stream to path", path);
        this.path = path;
    }
    destructor() {
        console.log("Closing file stream to path", this.path);
    }
    write(str) {
        console.log("Writing to file: ", str);
    }
}

async function run_with(resource, func) {
    try {
        func(resource);
    } catch(e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        resource.destructor();
    }
}

async function main() {
    console.log("Starting program");
    const fpath = "somewhere.txt";
    await run_with(new MockFileIO(fpath), (f) => {
        f.write("hello");
        f.write("world");
    });
    console.log("returning from main");
}

main();
```

##### Golang style

I have since found a paradigm that plays better with the way I personally use javascript.  It's based on golang's `defer` statement.  You simply wrap your code in a "scope" IIFE, and when that function is left **for any reason**, the deferred expressions are executed in reverse order, awaiting any promises.

Usage:

```
scope(async (defer) => {
    const s = await openStream();
    defer(() => closeStream(s));

    const db = new DBConnection();
    defer(() => db.close());

    throw new Error("oh snap"); // could also be return

    // db.close() then closeStream(s)
});
```

Scopes can return values and are async.  Here's an example of the same function written without, and then with the defer technique:

```
// without defer
async function getUser() {
    const conn = new DB();
    const user = await conn.getUser();
    conn.close();
    return user;
}
// this is bad! conn.getUser could throw an error.
```

becomes:

```
// with defer
async function getUser() {
    return await scope(async defer => {
        const conn = new DB();
        defer(() => conn.close());
        return await conn.getUser();
    });
}
// conn.close is always called, even after error.
```

That's basically it. Scopes can also be nested. The code to define scope is quite small:

```
async function scope(fn) {

    const stack = [];
    const defer = (action) => {
        stack.push(action);
    };
    const errs = [];

    try {
        return await fn(defer);
    } catch(e) {
        errs.push(e);
    } finally {
        while (stack.length) {
            try {
                await (stack.pop())();
            } catch(e) {
                errs.push(e);
            }
        }
        for (const e of errs.slice(1)) {
            await error("error in deferred action: " + e);
        }
        if (errs.length) {
            throw errs[0]; // eslint-disable-line
        }
    }
}
```

scope immediately executes the callback and collects all deferred functions into a stack.  When the function exits (either by return or error), the defer stack is popped until all the deferreds have been evaluated.  Any errors that happen in deferred functions themselves are collected into an error list, and the first one is thrown when the "scope" exits.  I've used this technique (this very code, actually) in a very critical, low-error-tolerance daemon I wrote for work, and it has stood the test of time.  I hope this helps anyone who is running into this situation.

Comment: Probably not important: In your "with defer" version of getUser() I see a lot of `async` and `await`, but it's all in service of two instances of `return await`. It seems to me that `return await` is often not actually useful. Why await if you are just immediately going to return from an async function which means it gets turned back into a promise again. `async` and `await` are unnecessary in these cases.

Comment: @Chris_F I'm just doing this to explicitly mark where things are asynchronous.  That way, when someone's like "but he didn't think about what happens if this is asynchronous", they can just immediately see that I was thinking about that.

Comment: Probably better just to let the discussion happen, it seems like leaving comments would have been better in hindsight

Answer (score 2):

You can use closures and `try ... finally` blocks to approximate RAII as discussed: http://jeanlauliac.com/raii-in-javascript/

For example,

```
function using(start, close, execute) {
    try {
        start.call(this);
        return execute.call(this);
    } finally {
        close.call(this);
    }
}

// specialize to some resource (inside a Context2D wrapper)
    usingScaledLineWidth(execute) {
        const tmp = this.context.lineWidth;
        const start = () => {
            this.context.lineWidth *= Math.abs(this.cf().a);
        };
        const close = () => {
            this.context.lineWidth = tmp;
        };
        return using.call(this, start, close, execute);
    }


// later RAII based usage
    stroke() {
        // have to manually do this because we're not scaling context
        if (this.context.strokeStyle !== "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)") {
            this.usingScaledLineWidth(()=>{
                this.context.stroke();
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the list of callbacks to be called on scope end. Call them all when needed.

This approach is used, for example to de-initialize additional handler attached to browser window. Callbacks containing de-initialization code are store in a list which is processed on window's unload event.

Unfortunately this approach is mostly unsuitable for scope management due to exception safety requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatelly, there isn't language statements for it (like destructors and determenistic destruction). You have to use `try { ... } finally { ... }` statements for it.

If you want to know how it could be done in a way similar to C++, pls take a look at https://github.com/cardinalby/ts-raii-scope when I tried to use raii container and TypeScript decorators for that. But I'm not sure it's good for production code, because other developers could be confused whith this approach.

If we are talking about TypeScript, also I think it could be implemented by [TypeScript transforms](https://dev.doctorevidence.com/how-to-write-a-typescript-transform-plugin-fc5308fdd943)